# iText: PDF Generation. One Template. More Inputs. One Output

Tags: java, pdf, itext

i try to generate a pdf with itext. First i read in a existing template and stamp the formulars in the method `stampFormular(Formular formular, PdfStamper stamper)`. The stamp method works. But i have a problem, with adding more formulars to the output file.

I want to stamp for each Formular the PDF Template "yellow". So i tried it with, the `document.add()`, but that doesn't work. So i tried to do this with pdf writer. But that doesn't work to. Any idea how i can stamp the pdf template with the one formular data, make a new page and stamp the same pdf template with the next formular data.

```
public static File createForm(List<Fomular> formulars) {
        Document document = new Document();
        File pdf = null;

        document.open();

        try {
            PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader('YELLOW');
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate,
                    new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
            PdfWriter writer;
            for (Formular f : formulars) {
                stamper = stampFormular(f, stamper);
                writer = stamper.getWriter();
                writer.newPage();
            }

            stamper.close();
            pdfTemplate.close();
            pdf = new File("output.pdf");
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdf);
        } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pdf;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:

You can't take the `PdfWriter` object from a `PdfStamper`, use `newPage()` and expect it to work. That's the equivalent of opening the hood of your car and start rewiring tubes that fit without knowing anything about the art of motor maintenance. When you want to add a new page to a `stamper`, you're supposed to use the `insertPage()` method as explained in the [documentation](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf).

Second observation: you're not telling us if you're flattening the content of the forms. If you do, then it's simple, just use the [example mentioned in the documentation](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=125) and you're all set. In other words: combine `PdfStamper` with `PdfSmartCopy`. Especially if you're using the same template over and over again, `PdfSmartCopy` will give you much better results than `PdfCopy` for the reason explained in [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf).

Suppose that your template needs to remain interactive, then you may have a problem for a reason that is also explained in that chapter: different visualizations of a field with a specific name must always have the same value. For instance: if your template has a field named `name`, then every occurrence of this field in the document must have the same value. If you don't want this, you need to rename `name`, for instance to `name1`, `name2`, etc...

Concatenation of templates that need to remain interactive used to be done with `PdfCopyFields` (see documentation). Here, the documentation is somewhat outdated. In the latest version of iText, we now have a method `addDocument()` in `PdfCopy` and `PdfSmartCopy`. This method allows you to add a full document at once, preserving the interactivity.